# Unlimited params in flash for Object?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

...args is for string. something possible for Objects ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`... args` actually creates an array of all the parameters to pass in, so this should work:

```
function showArguments(... args):void
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        trace(args[i]+", "+typeof(args[i]));
    }
}

showArguments({foo1:"bar1"},{foo2:"bar2"},"Hello",50);
```

Which traces:

```
[object Object], object
[object Object], object
Hello, string
50, number
```